# Processes for Insertion sort

Tags: c, algorithm, insertion-sort

I've been leariing sorting algorithms for couple of days. Presently i'm doing Insertion Sort. So the general algorithm is:

```
void insertionSort(int N, int arr[]) {
    int i,j;
    int value;
    for(i=1;i<N;i++)
    {
        value=arr[i];
        j=i-1;
        while(j>=0 && value<arr[j])
        {
            arr[j+1]=arr[j];
            j=j-1;
        }
        arr[j+1]=value;
    }
    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Now i've done this:

```
void print_array(int arr_count, int* arr){
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<arr_count;i++){
                printf("%d ",arr[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

    }

    void swap(int* m, int* n){
        int t = 0;
        t = *m;
        *m = *n;
        *n = t;
    }

    void insertionSort(int arr_count, int* arr) {
        int i, j;

        for(i = 0;i<arr_count;i++){
            for (j=0;j<i;j++){
                if (arr[i] < arr[j]){
                    swap(arr+i, arr+j); 
                  }
            }
            //if (i!=0)
            //print_array(arr_count, arr);
        }

    print_array(arr_count, arr);
    }
```

Now, my question is whats the diffrence between my custom approach and the traditional appraoch.Both have N<sup>2</sup> complexity....
Please help..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your "custom" approach is a bubble sort. Although it has the same order of complexity as an insertion sort, it is slower because it does more operations (a "swap" is three operations, whereas a "move" is only two operations).

Comment: @Ian Does'nt bubble sort swaps adjacent elements until the whole array is sorted...But im not swapping the adjacent element im taking a portion of the larger array and soting it and again taking  another portion of array, which contains the previous array.. and again sorting it..hence can it be concluded an Insertion Sort? After all insertion sort works like that taking a fragment of whole array sorting it using that sorted fragment to next bigger fragment containing the former fragment..

Comment: May I know the reaosns why my question is given a negative vote?

Comment: It's still an insertion sort as mentioned in @JohnBollinger's answer, but you perform the same number of operations (on average) as a bubble sort.

Answer (score 1):

At each iteration, the original code you present moves each element into place by moving elements in a cycle.  For an *n*-element cycle, that involves *n*+1 assignments.

It is possible to implement Insertion Sort by moving elements with pairwise swaps instead of in larger cycles.  It is sometimes taught that way, in fact.  This is possible because any permutation (not just cycles) can be expressed as a series of swaps.  Implementing an *n*-element cycle via swaps requires *n*-1 swaps, and each swap, being a 2-element cycle, requires 2+1 = 3 assignments.  For cycles larger than two elements, then, the approach using pairwise swaps does more work, scaling as 3*(*n*-1) as opposed to *n*+1.  That does not change the asymptotic complexity, however, as you can see by the fact that the exponent of *n* does not change.

But note another key difference between the original code and yours: the original code scans *backward* through the list to find the insertion position, whereas you scan *forward*.  Whether you use pairwise swaps or a larger cycle, scanning backward has the advantage that you can perform the needed reordering as you go, so that once you find the insertion position, you are done.  This is one of the things that makes Insertion Sort so good among comparison sorts, and why it is especially fast for inputs that are initially nearly sorted.

Scanning forward means that once you find the insertion position, you've only started.  You *then* have to cycle the elements.  As a result, your approach examines every element of the sorted array head on every iteration.  Additionally, when it actually performs the reordering, it does a bunch of unneeded comparisons.  It could instead use the knowledge that the head of the list started sorted, and just perform a cycle (either way) without any more comparisons.  The extra comparisons disguise the fact that the code is just performing the appropriate element cycling at that point (did *you* realize that?) and it's probably why several people mistook your implementation for a Bubble Sort.

*Technically*, yours is still an Insertion Sort, but it is an implementation that takes no advantage of the characteristics of the abstract Insertion Sort algorithm that give well-written implementations an advantage over other sorts of the same asymptotic complexity.

Comment: If i reverse the ieration for my second for-loop will it be more efficient?

Comment: @UzumakiSaptarshi No. Reversing the iteration order of the inner loop will have no effect on efficiency.

Comment: @UzumakiSaptarshi, if you reverse the iteration order of the inner loop, *and* make that loop stop when it reaches the insertion position (i.e. when it first discovers it does not need to swap), then *yes*, it will be more efficient, though still of the same asymptotic complexity.  But it will still do more work in most cases than the implementation you presented first.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between insertion sort algorithm and your custom algorithm is the direction of processing.The insertion sort algorithm is moving one by one the smaller elements in range to the left side while your algorithm is one by one moving the larger elements in range to the right side.

Another key difference is in the best case time complexity of insertion sort and your algorithm.
The insertion sort stops if the value < arr[j] is not satisfying so it have the best case complexity of O(n){when the array is already sorted} while your algorithm always searches from index 0 to j so it takes O(n^2) steps even when the array is already sorted.

Comment: The OP's custom sort is still an Insertion Sort.  It is just a poor implementation that indeed has the characteristics you describe.  It is thus instructive: it shows that some of the advantages we often attribute to the Insertion Sort *algorithm* do not come directly from the algorithm itself, but rather from some of the implementations it affords.